# diff algorithm implementation in python

Tags: python, diff

I checked out the source code of Python 2.6, and I want to study the diff implementation. However, I can not find the right source file. 
Could any one point me to whichever source file contains the algorithm implementation?

Comment: Um...  The source came with your Python implementation.  It's on your disk already.  What problems are you having finding your Python installation?

Comment: @S.Lott: to be completely fair, if the user installs a binary build (say, on Windows) of Python, it will not come with C sources

Comment: @Eli Bendersky: While quite true in general, this question isn't very general, is it?  It seems to be about `difflib`, which is pure Python and already installed.

Comment: @S.Lott: yes, but if you look at the OP's comment to Sven's answer, it's obvious he wasn't aware of the fact that difflib is pure Python and was actually looking for the "C code underneath"

Comment: Thanks Eli, you are right, difflib is pure Python implementation, which I am not aware of. I think I get my answer. Thanks for anyone.

Answer (score 6):

If by "diff implementation in Python" you mean the [`difflib` module](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html), then [here is the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/difflib.py).

There is also a [simple `diff` implementation based on this module](http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r271/Tools/scripts/diff.py?view=markup) in the Python source distribution.

Comment: yes, difflib is exactly what I mean. My point is how python use C to implemention this algorithm. So diff.py is not what I wanted. I think the source file should be under the directory of Modules in python source repository. However, I can not find it.

Comment: @user722607: `difflib` is a pure Python module, there's no C implementation of it